# How to use Get-AzWebApp command to list all the custom domains and Subscription names

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

How can I modify my command below to include the Subscription name in a CSV file just after the ResourceGroup name? I though the missing parameter is "Subscription" but it returns blank value. Thanks!

```
 $Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
   foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
       Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
       #Out-String -InputObject $sub
       Get-AzWebApp | foreach-object {$_} | select-object SiteName, DefaultHostName, ResourceGroup, @{n="EnabledHostNames";e={$_.EnabledHostNames -join ","}} | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\AzAppsUrl2.csv -append -NoType
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
    #Out-String -InputObject $sub
    Get-AzWebApp | foreach-object {$_} | select-object SiteName, DefaultHostName, ResourceGroup, @{n="Subscription";e={$sub.Name}}, @{n="EnabledHostNames";e={$_.EnabledHostNames -join ","}} | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\AzAppsUrl2.csv -append -NoType
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @Gaurav Mantri