# How to get list of all Azure subscriptions and resources using powershell (in specific format)

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to execute below powershell script to get list of all Azure subscriptions and resource details,

```
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $_.SubscriptionId
    Get-AzResource | Select Name,ResourceGroupName,Location,Type
    } | Export-Csv azureinventory.csv
```

However, its just dumping the data in one column in mentioned CSV file. I need each column to display Subscription name, Subscription ID, associated resource name, resource groupname, location, Type.

Please help to update the script accordingly.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69223504/how-to-use-get-azwebapp-command-to-list-all-the-custom-domains-and-subscription. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the script and it is not tested. the parameter value can be different here. Kindly change it by verifying it from Get-Azresource.

```
$resources = @()
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Set-AzContext
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
    $subscriptionId = $_.SubscriptionId
    Get-AzResource | ForEach-Object {
        $resources += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName  = $subscriptionName
            SubscriptionId    = $subscriptionId
            ResourceGroupName = $_.ResourceGroupName
            ResourceName      = $_.ResourceName
            ResourceType      = $_.ResourceType
            Location          = $_.Location
        }
        
    }
}
$resources | Export-csv c:\sompeath\somename.csv
```

Comment: Can you help where the $resourceID will fit in above script? I don’t want to give input in it. I need to fetch it from Azure.

Comment: Thanks. However, this script is giving Subscription name and id in one column, and Account, Environment, Subscription id, Tenant, TokenCache, VersionProfile, ExtendedProperties in separate column. It is not providing other details (resource group name, resource name, resource type and location. Please help.

Comment: I am not sure, what is wrong at your end. I am getting the results as expected. Can you please try modifying this command alone?  Export-csv c:\sompeath\somename.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: I used "$resources | Export-csv c:\sompeath\somename.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation" in Get-AzResource script block and it worked. Thanks Dilly. Also, do you know how to pull the tags on subscription?

Comment: @Amol G Yes, The tags are available in Get-AzResource. Please add Tags in PSCustomObject as we did for other parameters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below Script will help you to get the details of your ***current subscription name, tenant id, environment, account name***(or select your subscription after logging) and also the ***resource groups*** in that subscription, ***each resource group name, type, location*** of each resource available in that resource group, where you can export into excel sheet with a specific format like:

[image]

**Script:**

```
$ErrorActionPreference =  "Stop"  
try  {  
Connect-AZAccount  
Set-AzContext  -SubscriptionName  'Your Subscription Name' 
$rgs =  Get-AzResourceGroup  
foreach  ($rg in $rgs.ResourceGroupName)  
{  
Write-Output  "Checking Resource Group: $rg"  
Get-AzResource  -ResourceGroupName $rg |  Select  Name,  ResourceGroupName,  Type,  Location  |  Export-Csv  .\AzureResources.csv -Append  -Force  -NoTypeInformation  
 }  }  
catch  {  
Write-Host  "$($_.Exception.Message)"  -BackgroundColor  DarkRed  
}
```

**And the Output is:**

[image]

It will check the resource groups existing or not. After that, open the AzureResources.csv file exported in the path where you executed your script in the PowerShell.
The exported file shows the data of resource group name, each resource name, its type and location in the tabular format.

[image]

Comment: In your script, there is no mentioning of Subscription details as required by the original post.

Comment: It will give your current subscription details and resource groups names, resources (name, type, location) available in your subscription